# Error on Django Stripe: Request req_rbqdcpSrevU8AD: Must provide source or customer

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm getting the following error on my Stripe payment view:

```
InvalidRequestError at /advertise/post/
Request req_rbwdcpSrc9U8AD: Must provide source or customer.
```

I've simply copied the code from the [Stripe (Python) tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart#using-payment-information) so I'm not sure why it's not working.:

```
def pay(request, context):
    ad = get_object_or_404(AdvertisePost, hash=context['hash'])
    amount = ad.total_price * 100

    # Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
    # See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
    stripe.api_key = "sk_test_exhH9odKfkT4mxzbtVxuJOBZ"

    # Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
    # Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
    if request.method == "POST":
        token = request.POST.get('stripeToken')
        print('Token:', token) #prints None

        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=amount,
            currency='aud',
            description='Boosted Post',
            source=token,
        )

    context = {
        'amount': amount,
        'ad': ad
    }

    return render(request, 'advertising/pay.html', context)
```

and here's the form in my html:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_8rSK99eA02ntvemImQCeV6su"
    data-amount="{{ amount }}"
    data-name="My name"
    data-description="Example charge"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto"
    data-currency="aud">
  </script>
</form>
```

Any idea what the problem is?

PS: I'm using this for one-time payments. Not saving customers or anything like that.

Comment: If there's no token, then validation has failed, so you'll need to find the error in the post data. Check point 4; https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#tokens

Comment: Thing is, this error is just from the page loading. I don't actually submit the checkout form

Comment: Could it be that this is on my local development server which isn't HTTPS?

Comment: Ah right, so it's on the `GET`. The `data-key` attr to the script should be your public key. But your example doesn't match the key you've put in the view.

Comment: The `data-key` is my public key? (and my django view has my secret key). I changed a couple of the letters incase they were sensitive but I'm definitely using pk in the html form and sk in the django view - all copy pasted from stripe which automatically embeds the relevant keys into their places.

Comment: You said you don't actually submit the checkout form which means you should be calling it with a `GET` but it cannot be running the if statement if you have called the routine on a `GET` so how is it getting called initially?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue by adding business name at
https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/dashboard